# To prove that $(H,\cdot)$ is a subgroup of the group $(G,\cdot)$ it is sufficient to show that $H$ is closed with multiplication?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have proved that the set of invertible triangle matrices form a group (elements in $\mathbb{R}$). I now want to show that the subset where all diagonal-entries are $1$ make a subgroup. And I was wondering whether I also have to prove that the inverse-elements of elements in this subset are also in the subset or if it is sufficient to show that the subset is closed under multiplication.

Is there a theorem that says if a subset is closed than it is also a subgroup? I.e. that the inverses are also in this subset?

Comment: Consider the integers with the group operation being addition. The natural numbers are closed under addition, but hardly a subgroup.

Comment: It is enough with a certain kind of multiplication operation, namely that $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$ whenever $a,b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that the inverses are in there. For a simple example, note that both $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ are additively closed subsets of $(\Bbb Z,+)$.